# Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8) what does it mean?

Tags: java

I was looking at the sudoku code of the "mine" sudoku Android application and I've noticed this code:

```
selX = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8);
selY = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8);
```

What does `Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8)` and `Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8)` mean?

Comment: Think about it logically for a second

Comment: It takes the minimum of 8 and the maximum of x and 0. If x is negative the result will be 0; if x is positive and smaller than 8 the result will be x; if x is positive and higher than 8 then the result will be 8.

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(long, long)

Comment: max(int i1, int i2)
Returns the most positive (closest to positive infinity) of the two arguments.                                                     min(int i1, int i2)
Returns the most negative (closest to negative infinity) of the two arguments. This might help

Answer (score 1):

Break it down step by step using the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(long

> max(int a, int b) Returns the greater of two int values.
>
> min(int a, int b) Returns the smaller of two int values.

So Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8); breaks down to:

int maximum = Math.max(x,0);

int final = Math.min(maximum,8);

Answer (score 0):

First you take the maximum value of x and 0, so if x < 0, it will be zero.

Next take the minimum of the result and 8, so the maximum value will be 8.

It is about the same as:

```
  int selX = x;
  if (selX < 0) selX = 0;
  if (selX > 8) selX = 8;
```

or

```
  int selX = (x < 0) ? 0 : ((x > 8) ? 8 : x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one returns x, if x is between 0 and 8, 0 if x is less than 0, and 8 if x is greater than 8.

The second one works in a similar fashion.  So basically you're getting a number back that is guaranteed to be between 0 and 8, inclusive.

The Java [Math class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) describes what the `min` and `max` functions do in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Sudoku means 9 x 9 squares. You can index them from 0 to 8. Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8) guarantees that you get a number in that range. Is x > 8 then min(x,8) makes it 8. If x < 0 then max(x,0) makes it 0. That's all.